# Horribly huge table, how to break it up and distribute it along pages

Tags: longtable

I've got a table which is basically too big in every respect to fit on a single page. It is roughly 10x9 cells containing varying amount of text. Hence I have to use p{} environment to achieve some reasonable formatting.
simplified it looks like

```
|       | Scientific papers |
-----------------------------
|topics | Paper 1 | Paper 2 |
-----------------------------
|topic1 | yes     | no      |
-----------------------------
|topic2 | partial | somehow |
-----------------------------
```

But with 8 Papers and 9 or more topics.
Landscape (with rotatebox or lscape package) is a rather subobtimal solution, as the document will be distributed as PDF and print version.

I thought splitting the table at the long side could ease my pain. Simplified:

```
|       | Scientific papers |
-----------------------------
|topics | Paper 1 | Paper 2 |
-----------------------------
|topic1 | yes     | no      |
-----------------------------
|topic2 | partial | somehow |
-----------------------------
|       | Scientific papers |
-----------------------------
|topics | Paper 3 | Paper 4 |
-----------------------------
|topic1 | yes     | no      |
-----------------------------
|topic2 | partial | somehow |
-----------------------------
```

I then found out, I need longtable to make it distribute over more than one page. Longtable provides means to print the header again (caption, 1st line and the papers discussed) at the beginning of a new page. However, considering my split table, I need the header to change, when I reach the second part of the table, where the second batch of papers is discussed. Is that enterprise totally futile, and if not, how is it done?

Comment: At the beginning of the table, you have the `\endfirsthead` section, for the initial head, and the `\endhead` section for the head on subsequent pages. You also might be interested in the `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: You can't change the header in longtable (design error actually) If you are brave you can change it mid talbe but requires low level and mostly untested changes to longtable internals. You could use supertab/xtab instead the headings their are reset each page

Comment: or of course you can use multiple longtable starting a new one when you want the header to change

Comment: got it. That's what I expected. Very rare case which is not covered by any recent package. I'll go ahead and split it into two really independent tables (probably tabular will be sufficient as the parts are very likely shorter than a single page) and let latex put them where it wants to. Sometimes it is better to stop struggling. Thanks for the hints!